# Removing specific elements from JSON encoded array by use of PHP

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

I have a JSON file that looks a little like this:

```
  [
   {
    "uniqid":"sd54sd54f",
    "Make":"Toyota",
    "Start Prod":258147369,
    "End Prod":369147258
   },
   {
    "uniqid":"6sdf46sd",
    "Make":"BMW",
    "Start Prod":789456123,
    "End Prod":159487263
   },
  ]
```

What I need to do is remove an entire entry (uniqid, make, start prod and end prod) based on a uniqid that will be passed in through an HTTP POST request. So far all I have is:

```
  $var1 = $_GET['uniqid'];
  $file = 'cars.json';
  $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);  //im not sure if file_get_contnets is necessary...
  $unset_queue = array();

  foreach ( $json as $i => $item )
  {
        if ($item->uniquid == $var1)
        {
        $unset_queue[] = $i;
        }
  }

  foreach ( $unset_queue as $index )
  {
        unset($json->json[$index]);
  }

  $json = array_values($json);

  $new_json_string = json_encode($json);
```

When I run the code, I get no errors but the item is not removed...

EDIT: Here is the output issue at this point. Note the numbering of each car:

```
  {"1":
     {
      "uniqid":"sd54sd54f",
      "make":"Toyota",
      "start prod":"258147369",
      "end prod":"369147258"
     },
  "2":
    {
     "uniqid":"5372ab2109b05",
     "make":"6sdf46sd",
     "start prod":"789456123",
     "end prod":"159487263"},
    }
  }
```

Comment: `$file = cars.json;`  Looks like JS and not PHP.

Comment: @user1032531 lookat at the code, that's probably suppose to be a string. he uses `file_get_contents()` on it

Comment: It is filename but should be quoted. What does var_dump($unset_queue); say? You have extra json in unset clause?

Comment: @user1032531 its not JS. Im assigning a variable to the the actual json file that contains the information that has to be sorted through to remove what is being requested.

Comment: @AngularAddict was right, I should have quoted the file name. var_dump($unset_queue) returns the following: array(0) { }

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned that you will be passing your request through HTTP POST. In that case , in order to make your code to work, you should change `$var1 = $_GET['uniqid'];` to `$var1 = $_POST['uniqid'];`

Comment: I know that sounds logical, but I dont think it will work. I wrote another method in which the info to place into the json array was also passed through an HTTP POST. If I tried adding the info by way og $_POST[], it placed a null into the value for the key. Changing the $_POST to $_GET[] fixed the issue. Obviously I wont know for certain with this piece of code until I get all parts of it working...

Comment: If the variable you're after is appearing in your $_GET instead of $_POST it probably means you haven't declared the method attribute in your form (it should be `method="post"`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple function with the JSON variable [passed by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php):

```
function removeNode($uniqid, &$json) {
    $json = json_decode($json, true); // get associative array from json
    foreach($json as $key => $each) { // loop through
      if($each['uniqid'] == $uniqid)  // find matching unique
        unset($json[$key]);           // remove node from array
    }
    $json = json_encode($json);       // re-encode array as json
}
```

And use like this:

```
removeNode('6sdf46sd', $json);
```

Example: https://eval.in/150341

---

Specific use case for you:

```
$var1 = $_POST['uniqid']; // you're posting the data right?
$file = 'cars.json';
$json = file_get_contents($file);
removeNode($var1, $json);

echo $json; // updated JSON
// or if you want to update the file:
// file_put_contents($file, $json);
```

Comment: That seems to have worked. There is one issues though. Each of my entries in the JSON file is preceded by what looks to be an index i.e. {"0"{....}, "1"{...}, "2"{...}, etc} and the output is not in square brackets. I cant seem to find where to correct that in the code

Comment: If you could post an example of what your JSON looks like I can suggest how to implement it. Most likely that if it's array keys (indexes) like 0, 1 etc then this function will handle it fine without any modification... FYI - I've run my example demo and there are no numeric indexes/array keys in the output JSON.

Comment: @scowler I just posted my output. Please see the end of my original post.

Comment: @user2238415 please see this example https://eval.in/150838 where nothing is removed from the original JSON. Both this example and the one in my post do not add numeric indexes like your output has, what are you doing extra that is creating them?

Comment: @scowler I am not sure. I didnt add anything to the code that you suggested that I use. Obviously it looks like it might be something Im doing somewhere else in the code. Im reviewing it as we speak...

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a couple of things wrong:

- You are not checking that your code does what you think it does. It is important to check for errors.
- You can unset the item inside the first loop. The second loop is not necessary.
- Inside the second loop you are accessing an object and property that does not exist. When you decoded the JSON you specifically told it to return arrays.

First of all you should put this at the top of your script:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

That will show you every single error that occurs.

Second, you should fix your code. I just rewrote and commented your code. It is easier to show you than explain.

```
// Make sure that you are notified of all errors
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

// Get 'uniqid' from POST/GET array; show error if
// it is not set
$var1 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'uniqid', FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW);
if ($var1 === null) {
    die('The "uniqid" parameter is not set');
}
// Read data from file; show error if it does not work
$data = file_get_contents('cars.json');
if ($data === false) {
    die('An error occurred when opening "cars.json"');
}
// Decode JSON; show error if invalid JSON
$json = json_decode($data, true);
if ( ! isset($json[0]['uniqid'])) {
    die("The JSON was not decoded correctly");
}
// Go over each item in the array
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {

    // If the 'uniqid' equals GET parameter
    if ($value['uniqid'] == $var1) {

        // Then unset it using the item's $key position
        unset($json[$key]);
    }
}
// Encode it again
$new_json_string = json_encode($json);
```

If it is a GET request then you can use this instead:

```
// ...
$var1 = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'uniqid', FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW);
// ...
```

When you are done with the code, and you make it live, you should disable errors:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
```

That makes sure that people cannot see the errors. Error messages often include file names and such, which is not something people should see.

Comment: That works! And thank you for the tips on improving my code, i appreciate it. Quick follow up question though. As with the answer by @scrowler, the output of this results in each entry being numbered like so:  {"0"{....}, "1"{...}, "2"{...}, etc}. Any way to get rid of this numbering?

Answer (score -1):

```
$inputDatabase = array_values(json);
```

Comment: foreach ($jsonMaindata as $key => $each) { // loop through
                            if ($each['id'] == $id)  // find matching unique
                                unset($jsonMaindata[$key]);           // remove node from array
                        }


                        //$jsonMaindata[] = $insertArr;
                        if (!empty(file_put_contents($path, json_encode(array_values($jsonMaindata), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)))) {
}

Comment: first of all, do not post code into comments as it is unreadable. you can edit your post. also don't forget to use proper formatting for your code block. Then, you should add some explanations to your code to tell how it answers the question.